# C++ Allegro 5 bit depth problem windows and linux

Tags: c++, allegro

Well i'll be verbose as posible:

I have a main BMP (surface) that al_flip() to the display. I need low level access to that BMP surface, so there was not probem becouse plotting pixel to the lock() pointer in Windows is straight: positive pitch. In linux the pitch is negative. I had no problems i used #define
to let the system know if it was in linux or Windows.
The Windows version and the linux version of my app happly compiled and showed to the screen.
Now, my problem is that i have compiled HQX algorithm withing my app.
When i apply HQX to an Allegro BMP the linux system throws me "segmentation fault".

Does it mean that HQX algorithm doesn't works under linux or the there is a bit depth problem? I mean, if i run nvidia-settings from linux it says its running in 24 bits depth while Windows says that runs in 32 bits.

There is another thing: Allegro 5 linux is using Opengl and Windows is using Direct3d.

Can someone help me to tell me what the problem is?

Im kinda lost.